# Google Maps Jquery Tabs onload

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Really confused with google maps inside a tab. 
Where do I put the init function?
Normally we do body onload. But what about the tabs?

The tab is the jquery tab. 
The code is too large with multiple tabs for different levels of users. That tab itself is an anchor. 
I tried onclick on the tab, didn't work either. 
I really appreciate any help and suggestions.
Thank you.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was marked as duplicate, the question was not. People read
1: google maps
2 Tabs
Therefore duplicate. 
Sad.

If you are using the good old JV for the init code, the onload function goes exactly where we are used to: body tag. One less struggle that would take literally 5 seconds for a seasoned person.